# Fetching the number of words with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hey guys am developing a facebook app in which counts the number of words in  messages.

The main part of my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>


  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);

if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into this app.';
} else {

  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
    'into Facebook.';
}


}




  function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});


}



  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
appId      : '289533237896176',
cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                    // the session
xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });
 };










  (function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));




  function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me/inbox',function(response) {  for (var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
var thread = response.data[i];

for (var j=0;j<thread.comments.data.length;j++) {
    var comment = thread.comments.data[j].message;
console.log(comment); //prints  http://pastebin.com/4EaStYMX
}

}



}



);



}



</script>




<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,read_mailbox" onlogin="checkLoginState();">

</fb:login-button>





<div id="status">



<div id="fb-root"></div>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

The output of this is http://pastebin.com/4EaStYMX

What i need is that i have to find all the words in the full words from the message.

I have tried many methods but it didnt worked ..Hope you guys can help me out

Thanks in advance..

Comment: "I have tried many methods but it didnt worked" - like what?

Comment: split the spaces and the length is your count

Comment: @SterlingArcher Strictly speaking, that doesn't work if his data occasionally has double spaces between words (line 98 of x774y222 pastebin)

Comment: @SterlingArcher i have done that but it didnt worked

Comment: @KevinL can you please paste the code which will work

Comment: 1) trim spaces from either end, 2) split using `/\s+/`, 3) the length of the output array is your count.

Comment: @techfoobar i have tried the same thing but it didnt worked

Comment: "it didnt worked" is extremely vague

Comment: @techfoobar can you please paste the right code as an answer

Comment: @user3886467 - Can you post the code you tried, along with the console messages (if any) got got on running that? Must be some simple issue, since the above will *definitely* work.

Comment: @KevinL man i have tried the same method ..when i asked qus earlier some one gave me the same method so i tried ans it didnt worked

Comment: @KevinL reedited the answer now check

Comment: @techfoobar reedited the question ..now check

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, to count the number of words in each message, just pass each message to another function that counts them:

```
function countNumberOfWordsInMessage(message) {
    var numWords;

    // Trim extra spaces
    message = message.trim();

    // Separate words by space, and count total words
    numWords = message.split(' ').length;

    return numWords;
}
```

Test Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fM7Z7/

Comment: it returns 4,3,5,2,4 see what i need is to find the total words in the message not the length property

Comment: That number should be the total number of words in that sentence.

Comment: see when i output comment ..it displays many sentences ..what i need is to count the words from the sentences and sum it